# Display Pandas groupby results for defined groups only

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-3.4

I have a pandas dataframe of the following basic format:

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [12,12,12,12,45,45,45,51,51,51,51,51,51,76,76,76,91,91,91,91],
                        'measure': [3.2,4.2,6.8,5.6,3.1,4.8,8.8,3.0,1.9,2.1,2.4,3.5,4.2,5.2,4.3,3.6,5.2,7.1,6.5,7.3],
                        'status': [0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2]})
```

I want to get summary statistics for each 'status' based on the value in 'measure'. To do this, I use:

```
tempGroup = tempDF.groupby('status')
tempGroup['measure'].describe()
```

...and a series of summary stats are obligingly produced for each group in 'status'. However, in my actual database, the number of categories is much bigger and for some analyses, I only want to display results for a limited number of categories. In my above example, how could I display the summary statistics for status groups 1 and 2 only? I've tried various forms using .loc and other standard methods for slicing and dicing but to no avail. I've been able to step through each group individually using a for loop but that seems very inefficient - I'm assuming there must be an easier way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want stats for status 1 and 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [12,12,12,12,45,45,45,51,51,51,51,51,51,76,76,76,91,91,91,91],
                        'measure': [3.2,4.2,6.8,5.6,3.1,4.8,8.8,3.0,1.9,2.1,2.4,3.5,4.2,5.2,4.3,3.6,5.2,7.1,6.5,7.3],
                        'status': [0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2]})

# just show stats for 1, 2
groups = [1, 2]
tempDF.loc[tempDF.status.isin(groups)].groupby('status').describe()


Out[41]: 
                   id  measure
status                        
1      count   9.0000   9.0000
       mean   51.0000   4.3000
       std    27.3038   1.4186
       min    12.0000   2.1000
       25%    45.0000   3.1000
       50%    51.0000   4.3000
       75%    76.0000   5.2000
       max    91.0000   6.8000
2      count   4.0000   4.0000
       mean   61.2500   5.4500
       std    37.8627   2.1486
       min    12.0000   2.4000
       25%    41.2500   4.8000
       50%    71.0000   6.0500
       75%    91.0000   6.7000
       max    91.0000   7.3000
```

Comment: Thanks Jianxun Li. That works really well. In some ways I prefer the method described by EdChum because that allows group statistics to be displayed on-the-fly after a single groupby command. However, it only seems to display a single group at a time. Your method allows multiple selected groups to be displayed (even though a separate groupby command would need to be issued for each series of groups required). Nevertheless, I've marked this as the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groups`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups) attribute to get the groups and then use [`get_group`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group) and call [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.describe.html#pandas.Series.describe) for that group:

```
In [189]:
tempGroup.groups

Out[189]:
{0: [0, 6, 8, 11, 12, 15, 17],
 1: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 14, 16],
 2: [3, 10, 18, 19]}

In [188]:
tempGroup.get_group(0)['measure'].describe()

Out[188]:
count    7.000000
mean     4.614286
std      2.432714
min      1.900000
25%      3.350000
50%      3.600000
75%      5.650000
max      8.800000
Name: measure, dtype: float64
```

The groups are just the keys from `groups`:

```
In [190]:
tempGroup.groups.keys()

Out[190]:
dict_keys([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum. I like the idea of this approach because the display of groups can be done on-the-fly after groupby has been called. However, it seems that it will only output one named group at a time - at least, I tried to pass get_group() a list but that generates an error.

Comment: Yes the approach is different, here you define the groupby and then calc the stats as required so is computationally low, if you filter the df up front then you can't then query other groups